# WELD: Two beans cannot specialize the same Managed Bean

Tags: java, jboss-weld

I found this error trying to have two beans that specializes a third one in the same project. Even when one is activated through the beans.xml and other doesn't.

I haven´t found any reference of this behavior in the documentation and seems very annoying to me.

Is there any weld concept reasoning i am missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting on the jboss community it seems to be a bug on weld that is fixed on new versions.